# How to render flask jinja2 objects in a vuejs v-for draggable list?

Tags: flask, vue.js, jinja2

Here is my Vue

```
<div class="drag">
        <h2>List 1 Draggable</h2>
        <draggable id="cat1" v-model="list" :move="checkMove" class="dragArea" :options="{group:'people'}">
            <div v-for="element in list">${ element.name }</div>
        </draggable>
        <h2>List 2 Draggable</h2>
        <draggable id="cat2" v-model="list2" :move="checkMove" class="dragArea" :options="{group:'people'}">
            <div v-for="element in list2">${ element.name }</div>
            <p>another</p>
        </draggable>
    </div>
    <script>

        var vm = new Vue({
            el: "#main",
            delimiters:['${', '}'],
            data: {
                list: [{
                    name: "John"
                }, {
                    name: "Joao"
                }, {
                    name: "Jean"
                }],
                list2: [{
                    name: "Juan"
                }, {
                    name: "Edgard"
                }, {
                    name: "Johnson"
                }]
            }

            }
      </script>
```

This works great. The data from the list shows up properly and is draggable. Now I want to pass the following dict into the data object from flask so that I can render that instead.

The object when rendered with just `{{ data }}` looks like:

```
{u'uncategorized': [{'name': u''}, {'name': u'first'}, {'name': u'another'}]}
```

so you can see its about the same format as the object that gets passed into data:

```
{
                    list: [{
                        name: "John"
                    }, {
                        name: "Joao"
                    }, {
                        name: "Jean"
                    }],
                    list2: [{
                        name: "Juan"
                    }, {
                        name: "Edgard"
                    }, {
                        name: "Johnson"
                    }]
                }
```

But when I try and just substitute in `data: {{ data }}` in the vue, it doesn't render properly.

So what do I have to do to the data object in flask to make Vue "accept" it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all rendering data in a component like that is a bad practice in general. The best option would be to get the data from an api for better decoupling, but you if you really have to render the data in your template you should rather render it inside a custom property than inside the component, like you are doing it with `:option`.

Now to the actual problem. You are trying to render a python dictionary to a string into a a place where a json format is expected, that's obviously not gonna work. You'll have to convert it to json first, you can use the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for that.

Example taken from the documentation would look like this:

```
import json
json.dumps({"c": 0, "b": 0, "a": 0})
```

Keep in mind that the logical structure of your dictionary has to be the same as your expected json, not just optically.

Comment: can you elaborate on the first thing you said? Would it be better to fetch the data somehow in something like axios and then attach the data to that?

Comment: It's hard to generalize but I'd say most of the time it's the cleaner approach even thought you'll need an endpoint for the data and it's an async call adding extra requests. It depends on how asynchronous you want your application to be. Rendering data into the template for a vue component isn't bad practice in general, just the way you are doing it by adding it to the source code of the application. If you use the vue-api for doing it (e.g. using custom properties to pass the data from the outside template) there's not much speaking against that, except for higher coupling.